# C# WinForms ListView not displaying items/files/folders

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, listview

I want to display file names in listview but the problem is the listview is not showing any of the items. 
The strange part is the listview.items.count is indicating that items have been added correctly. 
Items are just not displaying in any type of listview.view.
EDIT: The ListView Is Drag and Dropped on Tab Control.

```cs
string[] files;
bool error = false;

    try   
    {        
          files = Directory.GetFiles(addDir /* this is the folder path*/, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // the code will jump here if there any access restrictions
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        error = true;
    }

    if(!error)
    {
        foreach (string fi in files)
        {
            string fnameonly = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi);
            _listView1.Items.Add(fnameonly);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is located this code? Is it in the same form as the _listVIew1_ variable? How do you get the reference to that variable _listView1_?

Comment: @Steve yes, the code is in the same form as the variabe listView1 is.

Comment: Sorry but there isn't enough context to understand what happens here. Use the debugger to check if the files array is filled with data. Also be sure to operate on the same form instance and not have create a new form instance.

Comment: Maybe you have set `OwnerDraw = true` in the designer/code? Maybe the ForeColor is the same as the BackColor?

Comment: @Jimi I checked and OwnerDraw = false and BackColor and ForeColor are different. the method => 
_listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
is also not invoking when I click anywhere on the listView1.

Comment: Show us the designer code for this control.

Comment: @LarsTech the listview alone is now working as i have tested but when I add it on the tab control it does not show items.

Comment: Unless you share the code that reproduces the problem for us, you make it hard to help you.  Using an underscore "_" for a designer control is not standard practice.  Make it look like you aren't referencing the correct control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it helps to create a new project, verify that it works and then add more features until you understand what broke your program. The example below just displays a ListView with two files. Make sure that this works on your machine. Then slowly add more code and always check that your program still works. I put all of the code in one file because it's easier to post on stack overflow but you can split it into separate files.

Also refer to the [ListView documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview?view=netframework-4.8)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp
{
    public class ListViewDemo : Form
    {
        public ListViewDemo()
        {
            var _listView1 = new ListView();

            string[] files = { @"C:\tmp\file1.txt", @"c:\path\to\file2.doc" };
            foreach (string fi in files)
            {
                string fnameonly = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi);
                _listView1.Items.Add(fnameonly);
            }

            AutoSize = true;
            Controls.Add(_listView1);    
        }
    }

    static class Program
    {    
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.Run(new ListViewDemo());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this actually worked. Thank You!
I`m actually creating a media player so I`m adding in features one by one but listView did not worked on the main project.

Comment: Edit: the listview when added on tab control does not show any items otherwise it is working.

Answer (score 0):

It was a really stupid mistake that took days to find out. I accidentally allocated memory to a ListView control which was created from drag drop actions.